# jQuery isn't functioning on different webhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, slider, nivo-slider

I just finished a website & went to upload it to the client's host, which is the same host that I use for my personal site. When I uploaded the site to his domain as an add on & tested the jQuery function, it doesn't run. I'm loading jQuery from Google via:

```
<!--/ jQuery Inclusion-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And it runs perfectly on my personal host setup, it just doesn't work at all on the new host. I called & got no resolve from tech support, was hoping that you guys could help me out.

**Nivo Slider & Fancybox working on my personal site:**

http://tinyurl.com/d3zley7

**Nivo Slider & Fancybox NOT working on client's site:**

http://tinyurl.com/d2egv2v

What could be causing this considering it's not required that the js is hosted on the server? I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you gone through the console errors?

Comment: You have some terrible, terrible markup in both of the pages. `<html>` and `<!DOCTYPE>` are repeated 3 times. While this may not be the exact cause of the problem, you should definitely fix that.

You are also initializing the slider twice.

Comment: I think there is something wonky with your static routing, as all of the jquery extensions (but not the remote jquery itself) are returning the main HTML page. [see this comparison of what I'm getting](http://i48.tinypic.com/zimxrb.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not a jQuery issue or whatsoever, is because all your scripts references return a 404 "page not found"

Your references start from the **root** `/` file

```
<script src="/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--/ Fancybox Script-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.4.pack.js"></script>

...etc
```

.... but they should be relative to directory `nd/` like

```
<script src="nd/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

... etc
```

... so is a path issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

nivoslider javascript does not exist on your clients site:

http://greencertifier.com/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js

but it exists on your site:

http://helmblanc.com/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js